# Nodejs mysql module not connecting to database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, serverside-javascript, node-mysql

I'm trying to do a simple test query to get the node mysql module working but it's not connecting to the database.
Here's my code in app.js:

```
var http    = require('http'),
io      = require('socket.io'),
sys     = require('sys'),
express = require('express'),
mysql = require('mysql'),
conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    port:'3000',
    user:'root',
    password:'pass',
    database:'some_database'
});

var port = 3000;

var app = express();

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
        res.render('./index.html',{test:'Hello'});
});

app.get('/home', function(req,res) {
        res.render('./index.html');
});

var chat_log = new Array();

var socket = io.listen(http.createServer(app).listen(port));

if(conn.connect()){console.log('yay');}else{console.log('whyyyy');};

console.log(conn);

conn.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
});

conn.end();
```

console.log(conn) returns the following:

```
{ domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _maxListeners: 10,
  config: 
   { host: 'localhost',
     port: '3000',
     socketPath: undefined,
     user: 'root',
     password: 'snareline1',
     database: 'test',
     insecureAuth: false,
     supportBigNumbers: false,
     bigNumberStrings: false,
     debug: undefined,
     timezone: 'local',
     flags: '',
     queryFormat: undefined,
     pool: undefined,
     multipleStatements: false,
     typeCast: true,
     maxPacketSize: 0,
     charsetNumber: 33,
     clientFlags: 193487 },
  _socket: 
   { _connecting: true,
     _handle: 
      { fd: -1,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread] },
     _readableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: false,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        calledRead: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        objectMode: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        data: [Object],
        readable: [Function],
        connect: [Object],
        close: [Object],
        error: [Object],
        drain: [Function: ondrain] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     _writableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        objectMode: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        buffer: [] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: false,
     onend: null,
     destroyed: false,
     errorEmitted: false,
     bytesRead: 0,
     _bytesDispatched: 0,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     pipe: [Function],
     addListener: [Function],
     on: [Function],
     pause: [Function],
     resume: [Function],
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true },
  _protocol: 
   { domain: null,
     _events: 
      { drain: [Object],
        error: [Object],
        close: [Object],
        data: [Function: ondata],
        end: [Object],
        handshake: [Function],
        unhandledError: [Function] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     readable: true,
     writable: true,
     _config: 
      { host: 'localhost',
        port: '3000',
        socketPath: undefined,
        user: 'root',
        password: 'snareline1',
        database: 'test',
        insecureAuth: false,
        supportBigNumbers: false,
        bigNumberStrings: false,
        debug: undefined,
        timezone: 'local',
        flags: '',
        queryFormat: undefined,
        pool: undefined,
        multipleStatements: false,
        typeCast: true,
        maxPacketSize: 0,
        charsetNumber: 33,
        clientFlags: 193487 },
     _connection: [Circular],
     _callback: null,
     _fatalError: null,
     _quitSequence: null,
     _handshakeSequence: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _callback: undefined,
        _ended: false,
        _callSite: [Error],
        _config: [Object],
        _handshakeInitializationPacket: null },
     _handshaked: false,
     _destroyed: false,
     _queue: [ [Object] ],
     _handshakeInitializationPacket: null,
     _parser: 
      { _supportBigNumbers: false,
        _buffer: <Buffer >,
        _longPacketBuffers: [],
        _offset: 0,
        _packetEnd: null,
        _packetHeader: null,
        _onPacket: [Function],
        _nextPacketNumber: 0,
        _encoding: 'utf-8',
        _paused: false } },
  _connectCalled: true,
  state: 'disconnected' }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have a mySQL server running in localhost?

Comment: That's an awful lot of code for a problem like this. Do try and keep it to a *minimum*.

Comment: Yes, my server is running on localhost. And I'll edit the code so only the relevant parts show up.

Comment: Could you try catching an error when you establish your connection? conn.connect(function (err) {console.log(err);});

Comment: No error is thrown when I try that.

Comment: Is your mysql server running at port 3000 ?

Comment: Yes it's running on that port. Any other one I try gives me an access denied error.

Comment: SR5 got what's probably the issue: you are attempting to use port 3000 both for your node app and for your mysql connection. Figure out which port is mysql running on and point your connection to it. If you get an access error you are probably using incorrect credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    port:'3306',
    user:'root',
    password:'pass',
    database:'some_database'
});
```

Comment: Default port for mySql is 3306. You can refer this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/access-denied.html (In your above code, mysql port and your node app port 3000 are conflicting).

Comment: Oh okay.. I think I might have to try to uncomment the skip networking thing in mysql.conf. If that works then you get the check mark :)

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know how to enable networking for mysql on a mac would you? Apparently there's no mysql.conf file.

Comment: I ended up switching to another mysql user that was registered on a different host ip and somehow that worked. Thanks for the help.